# Cannot sync the status of a SVN versioned folder between two machines

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recon the title per se is not really esplicative, but I was not able to come up with a better one. Suggestions are really welcome.

I'm using SVN to keep track of some important files between multiple machines. On Machine A, I've created and committed empty folders and sub-folders to store some data in. On Machine B, a collegue created the same folders and sub-folders structure, with the same names and everything.

At the moment, Machine A has the folder tree committed, Machine B as the same folder tree, not committed.

I go on and tell my collegue that I've already created the folder tree, and to kindly update Machine B. He does so by deleting the non-committed folder tree and SVN update (using Tortoise SVN).

Tortoise SVN tells that update to revision x is done, nothing added and the committed folder tree is not added to working copy on Machine B.

Can somebody help me understanding why is this happening, how to fix it and how to prevent it in the future?

---

From what I understand, a possible cause is that either the working copy thinks she is in locally changed and current state, so no update is performed. But if I try to commit, the locally deletion is not in the changelog of tortoise SVN (I did not commit the Machine B copy to avoid disrupting even more the environment).

I don't have SVN command line apparently on the machines.

I tried SVN update on Machine A, it goes to revision x (same as above), but the folder tree appears unchanged (expected).

Comment: I would try svn cleanup: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html on machine B with all checked options and then update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the whole "machine B"-working copy to a spare place
2. Do a new checkout on Machine B to the original place
3. Copy everything from spare (except .svn folder(s)) into the new working copy.